# bootstrap data-source issue w flask/wtform

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap

i'm passing in a list for bootstrap autocomplete function.

template code 
load in list

```
<script> var autoc = {{ autoc|tojson|safe}};</script>
```

wtform

```
{{form.name(**{"data-provide":"typeahead","data-source": autoc })}}
```

the rendered html looks like

```
<script> var autoc = ["John","Leon","Mark","Andrew"];</script>

<input data-provide="typeahead" data-source = "['John','Leon','Mark','Andrew']"
```

I know the reason the autocomplete isn't working because the data-source entries are in single quotes, not double.  I can't figure out how to fix.  I've been working on this for hours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the value for the data-source key a json string rather than just a list.

```
{% with autoc_json = autoc|tojson|safe %}
     {{form.name(**{"data-provide":"typeahead","data-source": autoc_json })}}
{% endwith %}
```